# Universal Windows Store app binding not working with strange error

Tags: windows-phone, windows-phone-8-emulator

I have been seeing the exact problem described here:

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/7ee9f7a1-cebc-49cb-9df5-75728e51183f/contact-picker-not-bringing-through-thumbnail?forum=winappswithcsharp

the solution was working perfectly until I've checked the "Fields" property of a "contact" object returned by

```
Contact contact = await contactStore.GetContactAsync(contact.Id);
```

in Visual Studio's Watch.

Now each time I call

```
await ContactManager.RequestStoreAsync()
```

application waits indefinitely and does not respond.

I've tried to run different emulators, deleted application, cleaned it. I've also restarted my computer and tried to run this application on debug and release targets. I've also tried it on real life device. Nothing helps.

Any idea how can I bring it back to working state?

Comment: Did you enable capabilities for ContactManager?

Comment: Yes I did, the problem is probably with some thread specific thing

Answer (score 0):

It seems that calling that method from out of UI thread cause this behavior